# adding cookies to my site

Tags: php, cookies

im not good at programming in php so I need your help.

I have existing login system with home page and registration, that has session() in, but I need cookies instead, I have no idea how to apply cookies to my page, I know how cookies work and stuff but it just wont work when I apply the code to my site..Can someone show me how to apply the code so it actually works?
 how to set cookie here...
Thanks!

home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
header("Location: index.php");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>
```

Comment: [see this](http://www.phpnerds.com/article/using-cookies-in-php/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On successfull login set cookie like this,

```
setcookie('is_loggedin', '1');
```

then

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['is_loggedin'])) { 
     // user is logged in    
} else {
     header('Location: login.php');// user not logged in, redirect to login page
}
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) for more information.

Comment: how do i apply this to existing code, because when i do, login wont work anymore..

Comment: where ever session is there for login part, replace with cookies,

Comment: it does work now, thanks!

Comment: which part is not working??

Comment: works! Thansk!
Now I have different question, how do I include username and password inside cookie, this is for uni project, so i need to include both i know is not safe.

Comment: check the link i have added in comments... that is a tutorial...

Comment: still cant figure it out, can you show me example based on my code please?

Comment: i used [this](http://www.phpnerds.com/article/using-cookies-in-php/2) to learn about cookies.

Comment: it wont show how to pull username for cookies from database if you know what i mean

Comment: while setting cookie, `setcookie('username',name from form);`

Comment: use `echo $_COOKIE['username'];` to display the value.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you set a cookie,

```
setcookie("cookie_name","cookie_value",time()+3600*24*30);
```

Once you have set it, this is how you access the value of it.

```
$val = $_COOKIE['cookie_name'];
```